# JPQL Update Statement with Join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I've never used JPQL before, and I need to use it to batch update the values in a specific column. The column exists in the table, but the entity class was set up without a variable for it. I can't use the exact data, but the setup would be something like this to give you an idea:

**Database Columns**

```
Books:
book_id book_title author_id

Authors:
author_id first_name last_name
```

**JPA Entity Classes**

```
Books:
private Integer bookId;
private String bookTitle;
private EAuthor author;

Authors:
private Integer authorId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
```

In the Books entity class, there's a getter & setter for the author_id, but it calls it from the author entity. My dilemma now is I need to batch update all book_titles with the same author_id and I'm unsure how to write the JPQL query statement to do this. I tried:

```
String queryUpdate = "UPDATE books b SET b.book_title = :bookTitle"
                            + " WHERE b.author = :authorId";
```

and

```
String queryUpdate = "UPDATE books b SET b.book_title = :bookTitle"
                            + " WHERE b.author.authorId = :authorId";
```

Both queries said both b.author.authorId and b.author were invalid identifiers. Would it make be possible to write 2 separate queries? 1 query as a select statement where I can use joins and then the 2nd to update the result set of the first query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPQL is a poor choice for the job. `b.author.authorId` is not allowed, as it would translate to an SQL `JOIN`. Neither does JPQL support subqueries in `UPDATE` statements. You *could* map the `author_id` to a property in `Books`:

```
@Column(name = "author_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Long authorId;
```

With the above in place, you could just do:

```
UPDATE Books b SET b.book_title = :bookTitle WHERE b.authorId = :authorId
```

but you would have to live with altering your domain model just to acommodate a single case with an `UPDATE` query.

You should be able to split the task into two queries like so:

```
List<Long> ids = em.createQuery("SELECT b.id FROM Books b WHERE b.author.id = :authorId", Long.class)
    .setParameter("authorId", authorId)
    .getResultList();
em.createQuery("UPDATE Books b SET b.bookTitle = :bookTitle WHERE b.id IN :ids")
    .setParameter("ids", ids)
    .setParameter("bookTitle", bookTitle)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Or, you could simply update the entities from code:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT b.id FROM Books b WHERE b.author.id = :authorId", Book.class)
    .setParameter("authorId", authorId)
    .getResultList()
    .forEach(book -> book.setBookTitle(bookTitle));
```

Comment: Splitting up the queries did the trick. The application is huge and the entities this involved are core to the application, so I didn't want to have to change the entity classes if possible, and potentially 1000+ records would need to be updated at a time, so I also didn't want to iterate over each of them individually. Thanks!